# Integer solution to the following equation with two variable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, number-theory

What is a general methodology to find the integer solutions for the following equation :

$$xy - f(x)=0$$

here, specially $f(x)$ is purely analytic (not algebraic).
(Can any generalized Hasse principle exists or Braur Manin obstruction?).
Furthermore , If it is known that it has infinitely many integer solutions can we find solutions or number of solution under some given value of either variable .

Comment: I very much doubt there's a general method for this kind of problems...

Comment: It's hard enough to find integer solutions when $f$ is restricted to be a polynomial. Expanding to the much larger class of analytic functions is hopeless.